# Program Stops at the Beginning of My Program

Tags: java

i am new to programming, and i was wondering if i could get some help. My program stops running at `System.out.println("To calculate interest, we need three values. the first is the percent of interest. The second is the time the interest has to be applied for. The third is the amount of money the interest is being applied on.");`. I am open to any suggestion. Also, please point out anything else wrong with this program. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Interest

{

    double userInput;

    double interest;

    double time;

    double amount;

    double answer;

    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {

         System.out.println("To calculate interest, we need three values. the first is the percent of interest. The second is the time the interest has to be applied for. The third is the amount of money the interest is being applied on.");

    }

    {   

        System.out.println("Please enter your percent of interest in a decimal format: ");

        userInput = myScanner.nextDouble();



        if(myScanner.hasNextDouble())

            {

                interest = userInput;

            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter a integer for your percent of interest.");

            }

    }

    {

        System.out.println("Please enter the time the interest is applied for: ");

        userInput = myScanner.nextDouble();



        if(myScanner.hasNextDouble())

            {

                time = userInput;

            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the time the interest is applied for.");

            }

    }

    {

        System.out.println("Please enter your amount of money that the interest is applied to: ");

        userInput = myScanner.nextDouble();



        if(myScanner.hasNextDouble())

            {

                amount = userInput;

            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the amount of money that the interest is applied to.");

            }

    }

    {

        answer = (amount * interest * time);

    }

    {

        System.out.println("Your interest is $" + answer + ".");

        System.out.println("Your total payment is $" + (answer + amount) + ".");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of all the extra braces; they're outside your `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{

    System.out.println("To calculate interest, we need three values. the first is the percent of interest. The second is the time the interest has to be applied for. The third is the amount of money the interest is being applied on.");

// } <-- remove

// { <-- remove

    System.out.println("Please enter your percent of interest in a decimal format: ");

// -----SKIP-----

// } <-- remove

// { <-- remove
    System.out.println("Your interest is $" + answer + ".");

    System.out.println("Your total payment is $" + (answer + amount) + ".");
} // leave this here (end of method)
```

Comment: sorry bout askin dumb questions bc im really new to programming, but how do i get the program to advance? the first statement is displaying, but its not moving on, but the program is still running. Any advice?

Comment: @DanielLonarkar It's probably waiting for input.

Comment: I give it input but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you are writing instance blocks and in main method,you did not make object creation.instance blocks are executed when you create object of class.if you want to execute those instance block you should write `YourClass myclass = new YourClass()`in your main method and when you run main function,those blocks outside of main()will be executed OR you should write these blocks in main method just like @shmosel's example.